# How to Inspect ModelStateDictionary in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm getting a "An item with the same key has already been added" when using the ModelStateToTempData filter from MvcContrib. I'm trying to figure out what the duplicate key is but can't figure out how to inspect the model state at the point that the filter is adding the keys. Is there any way to do so without hooking up to the MvcContrib source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include the PDB's in the same folder as the mvccontrib DLL. That'll allow you to see source during debugging and step through mvccontrib without including the whole source projects.